# Differential system backup at startup

Tags: linux, backup, startup, incremental-backup

I got a Linux Ubuntu Server, where system has its own 5 gig partition. Ive recently made a backup of this system partition into an .img file using `dd`.
Since it is a system partition I needed to boot using live CD, mount the drive and then call dd from the terminal.

Is there any solution how the system could possibly make a differential backup of itself at every startup?   (against this .img file I have previously created)

Thanks!

Comment: It is not completely clear what are you trying to do - what would be the result of this differential backup? A binary patch file for old .img file? Or differential backup of the files from the filesystem in .img file. If later, in what format and where should those be written? Also, making a system backup process that can only run at startup does not sound as particularly good plan.

Comment: Well the process should find the differences between actual system partition and its image in the .img file and update the .img file, so its always the actual image of the system. Actually the reason why to run this while booting up is that you cant get exclusive access to the partition while the system already booted up (otherwise I would probably use CRON task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might checkout using [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/examples.html) for local backup